# Trigger to Pusher.com does nothing

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am trying to use `vinkla/pusher` on Laravel 5.1

This is what I've added to `app.php`:

`Vinkla\Pusher\PusherServiceProvider::class` as a service provider

`'LaravelPusher' => Vinkla\Pusher\Facades\Pusher::class,` as a facade.

Route:

```
Route::get('/api/bid', [
    'uses' => 'APIController@bid'
]);
```

And this is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\CurrentAuction;
use App\User;
use App\Bid;
use Session;
use LaravelPusher;

class APIController extends Controller
{
    public function getCurrentAuction()
    {
        // snip...
    }

    public function bid(User $user) {
        // Whole heap of things done with $user...
        // snip...

        $data['bids'] = 1;
        LaravelPusher::trigger('bid_channel', 'NewBid', $data);
    }
}
```

Calling that method does everything except trigger the pusher event.

I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you verifying that nothing is happening? Do you have any debug output? I'd recommend getting some debug information as outlined in the [Pusher PHP library debug section of the README](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#debugging--logging). You should be able to use `LaravelPusher::set_logger( $your_logger );`. If you post the debug output it should be possible to work out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when using Laravel Homestead/Vagrant, pusher, broadcasting or anything like that doesn't want to work for me.

I pushed everything up to a live server and it worked without any code changes.